# Material3 Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, material3

I add Searchbar and SearchView component  material3(v1.1.1) to project
fragment home
when run project Error :
Error :

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52 in com.besoyeit.appbesoyeit:layout/fragment_home: Binary XML file line #52 in com.besoyeit.appbesoyeit:layout/fragment_home: **Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchView**
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52 in com.besoyeit.appbesoyeit:layout/fragment_home: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....

please help me!

---

Gradle
///material
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.1")

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FragmentHome">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_main_constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        android:id="@+id/searchBar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="4dp" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
    android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/searchView_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/searchBar_main">
   
</com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `androidx.compose.material3:material3` artifact is for [**composables**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) that implement the [Material3 guidelines](https://m3.material.io). The code you're using is a [views-based layout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout).

If you want to use the `SearchView` XML view, you'll have to use the [views-based library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/) which can be found under the `com.google.android.material:material` artifact:

```
dependencies {
  implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
}
```

As of the time of writing, the [latest stable version is 1.9.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.9.0).

If this is your first time using the Material Components for Android library in your project, I would recommend you follow the [getting started guide to setup the library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.9.0/docs/getting-started.md), and then you should be able to use the [`SearchView` XML view](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.9.0/docs/components/Search.md) with no issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot . The problem was solved
The problem was the inheritance of the theme, which I had to do
Your suggestion to read the link below was great and I realized the problem by reading it
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.9.0/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: ok  I add  theme  parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar"  
and other style by material builder pluging and problem  solved
but now have a new problem 
AppbarLayout not visible in Design view  though project is runable and start successful
eoror:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Motion easing theme attribute must be an @interpolator resource for ?attr/motionEasing*Interpolator attributes or a string for ?attr/motionEasing* attributes.